# Difference between two dates in mysql & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know the difference between two dates(joinon in table's field) of different id's in same table in PHP. Attachement of my table structure as attached below.

[image]

Displayed dates are shown at the mentioned fields shown at the below screen shots.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

my php code are mentioned below

```
<table id="dataTableExample1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th class="text-center">Days</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Time Interval</th>
            <th>Attachment</th> 
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php 
    $proj_id = $_GET['proj_id'];
    $proj = mysql_query("select * from project_historytl where proj_id='$proj_id' order by proj_histl_id desc") or die(mysql_error());
    ///echo "select * from project_historytl where proj_histl_id='$proj_id' order by proj_histl_id desc";exit();
    $s = 0;
    while ($getannexure = mysql_fetch_array($proj))
    { 
        $s++;
    ?> 

        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Day <?php echo $s;?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $getannexure['joinon']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $getannexure['proj_history_title']; ?></td> 
            <td> </td> 
            <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $getannexure['attachment']; ?>" target="_blank">View</a> </td>
            <td> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-add btn-sm"><span class="elusive icon-pencil" title="edit"></span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer2"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button> 
            </td>
        </tr> 

    <?php  
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the result like this format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsFto.png)

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Use [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) to calculate difference between  dates.

Comment: You should search for the method: php explode() if you do this $date1 = explode('-', $joinon) it will make an array $date1[2019,03,21] than u can compare them

Comment: What exactly do you expect the column "Time Interval" in your HTML table to be? The interval between which dates...?

Comment: difference of 1st id's joinon minus 2nd id's joinon..........joinon[21-03-2019]-joinon[19-03-2019];

Comment: What if there are 3 rows? How do you determine which two to use?

Comment: last id's joinon - current id's joinon

Comment: Then what about the first entry? There will be no last row when you fetch the first row.

Comment: You should also stay away from using `mysql_` - use `mysqli_*` or PDO with a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of comparing two dates is as follows:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

In your case, it's probably easier if you change the structure a little so that all the array rows are stored in a single array before you start comparing dates.

Replace your `while()` loop with the following:

`while ($getannexure[] = mysql_fetch_array($proj, MYSQL_ASSOC)){}`

The run the following `foreach()`:

```
foreach($getannexure as $id => $row) {
    if (!empty($getannexure[$id + 1])) {
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($row[$id + 1]['joinon']);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($row[$id]['joinon']);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $getannexure[$id]['diff'] = $interval->format('%R%a days');
    } else {
        $getannexure[$id]['diff'] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Now loop thru the `$getannexure` array like you have and you'll have an added `diff` value that you can use.

Comment: I dont know how to display the difference between two dates from table

Comment: I want to calculate from id 1 joinon and id 2 joinon

Comment: I updated my answer to include code that is specific to your current structure. Have a look, let me know if it works.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$interval' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\xampp\htdocs\metco_crm\listprojhistory.php on line 148

Comment: I just realised your table rows are in reverse chronological order, so I updated the code with a better example. Try it now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks! Just removed it. Too early in the morning for me!

Comment: It display only First record

Comment: `if (is_array($getannexure[$id + 1]))` would still throw _"Undefined index"_ on the last row. Use `isset()` or `!empty()` instead. No reason to check if it's an array. If it exists, it will be. Also, I would recommend defining `$getannexure[$id]['diff'] = null;` before the if-statement or the last record won't have that key at all.

Comment: I just realized something. `$getannexure` is actually an array containing one record (one row) in this context. So, your `foreach()` would iterate through the row _values_ not the rows them self. `$id` will be the column name and `$row` will actually be the column value so the above code won't work at all.

Comment: Make sure you add the `[]` to the `while()` loop, and it should create a numerical array.

Comment: anybody help me!

Comment: @SixthStarTechnologies, after you run your while loop, do a `var_dump($getannexure);exit;`, let me know what you get. You should get a numerical array.

Comment: it will display the array values numeric arrays

Comment: Try adding `MYSQL_ASSOC` to the query. I have updated the answer.